# BigQuery Reservations API: Location EU not possible

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble with the BigQuery slot reservation API. It seems the only valid location I can input is "US". I'm getting "Location ID: EU is invalid.".
However, reservations are definitely possible for EU in the Console as well. I've also tried regions and zones with no luck...

Example code:

```
region = 'EU'
admin_project_id = 'admin_project'

def api_builder():
    res_api = ReservationServiceClient()
    parent_arg = "projects/{}/locations/{}".format(
        admin_project_id, region)
    return(res_api, parent_arg)

def purchase_commitment(slots=500):
    api = api_builder()
    res_api = api[0]
    parent_arg = api[1]
    commit_config = CapacityCommitment(plan='FLEX', slot_count=slots)
    commit = res_api.create_capacity_commitment(parent=parent_arg,
                                                capacity_commitment=commit_config)
    print(commit)
    return commit.name
```

Comment: Is your admin project located in EU?

Comment: I believe so, but I couldn't find a way to find out the location of the whole project. The admin project is only a shell project with reservations api enabled. The slots I have available there are definitely only for location EU.

Comment: Can you run `curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone`
in your shell (admin project) to find the region?

Comment: Thanks, this gives me "projects/xxxxxx/zones/europe-west4-b", so it seems to be ok?

Comment: The documentation says "You can assign any project that's in the same organization and region as the administration project where you created the commitment" so if your region is that same for your admin project and your actual project, it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is an issue with the reservations api backend.

Link to Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162759936